iOS Shortcut "Run Javascript on webpage" to scrape Mastercard Conversion rates
first of all I want to say that my programming knowledge is very basic, therefore I use GPT a lot, also this is my first stackoverflow question, so my explainging could be better. That said, I am trying to make an iOS shortcut that inputs 4 different values into a Mastercard Conversion rate web "https://www.mastercard.com.ar/es-ar/consumidores/soporte/convertidor-moneda.html" to later scrape the exchange rate and add it to a Numbers spreadsheet (I think those last 2 steps wont be a problem). The problem I am having is that the first field is overwritten from ARS to EUR and the 3rd is left empty, however, if i erase step 3 from the code (see code below), it works perfectly (obviously 3rd field is left empty).
This is the code i managed to get:
// Step 1: Set the "From" Currency to ARS
var fromDropdownButton = document.getElementById('tCurrency');
fromDropdownButton.click(); // Open the dropdown menu for "From" currency
var fromOptions = document.querySelectorAll('ul.dropdown-menu li a');
for (let option of fromOptions) {
    if (option.textContent.includes('ARS')) { // Match the "ARS" currency
        option.click(); // Select "ARS"
        break;
    }
}

// Step 2: Set the "Amount" to 10000
var amountField = document.getElementById('txtTAmt');
if (amountField) {
    amountField.value = "10000"; // Input the amount
    amountField.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true })); // Trigger input event
}

// Step 3: Set the "To" Currency to EUR
var toDropdownButton = document.getElementById('cardCurrency');
toDropdownButton.click(); // Open the dropdown menu for "To" currency
var toOptions = document.querySelectorAll('ul.dropdown-menu li a');
for (let option of toOptions) {
    if (option.textContent.includes('EUR')) { // Match the "EUR" currency
        option.click(); // Select "EUR"
        break;
    }
}

// Step 4: Set the "Bank Fee" to 0
var bankFeeField = document.getElementById('BankFee');
if (bankFeeField) {
    bankFeeField.value = "0"; // Input the bank fee
    bankFeeField.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true })); // Trigger input event
}

// Completion message
completion("Form filled successfully: From=ARS, Amount=10000, To=EUR, Bank Fee=0");

Thank you in advance to anyone who offers help :).

From a cursory look over the page's markup, it seems that both dropdown controls have their own ul.dropdown-menu, so your second call to document.querySelectorAll('ul.dropdown-menu li a'); includes the "From" field's dropdown items as well as the "To" field's dropdown items. I would suggest either changing your selector to target the second control's menu specifically, such as by changing it to:
var toOptions = document.querySelectorAll('#mczRowD ul.dropdown-menu li a');

I'm a bot account. This answer was posted by a human to get me enough reputation to use Stack Overflow Chat.

It worked! Thank you so much! I managed it to work by manually writing EUR then picking the first option, but this is way cleaner. Thank you again

Hello @Toasty, i thought the scraping part was going to be easy, however im having a lot of problems, i want to get the calculated echange rate and pass it down to shortcuts as a variable, any ideas?
